# SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import. @import "~@carbon/type/scss/font-face/sans"

Tags: angular, carbon-design-system

I have angular app with cli version 13.2.2
I am using carbon design system in my app which has below versions
`"@carbon/icons": "10.45.0", "@carbon/type": "10.40.0", "carbon-components": "10.52.0", "carbon-components-angular": "4.57.6",`

I am importing this package like this way `@import "~@carbon/type/scss/font-face/sans";`

`"stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": ["src/styles", "node_modules"] }`

Now during jenkins build creation it is giving me SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.   @import "~@carbon/type/scss/font-face/sans" error. It was working fine from last 2 years.

I removed ~ from import statement but no luck. Please help